# How to include LESS files in web page using Web Essentials?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, less, web-essentials

I have installed web essentials 2013 and I created a default MVC project for testing purposes to try LESS functionality.

I removed all the bootstrap CSS files and i put a folder named `less` inside `Content` with all the `bootstrap`'s `.less` files but when i right click on them the `web essentials` menu is all grayed out and it doesn't compile anything... 
How can I include less files inside a web page with auto compile using `Web Essentials`. Is that possible?

The settings of web essentials are the following:

```
"Less": {
    "CompileOnBuild": true,
    "CompileOnSave": false,
    "EnableChainCompilation": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": "css",
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "StrictMath": false
}
```

Comment: I use web essentials but do not bother with the compiling. I just add the `less.js` file (for compiling in the browser) and reference the `styles.less` (or whatever yours is called). this way anybody that uses a project (another member on the team) that doesn't use web essentials will always have the compile files

Comment: @RobScott Hmm...[in/for production](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage)?

Comment: precisely what I'm talking about. only for production what you'd do is compile the LESS file (I use WinLESS) into the CSS (or use web essentials I guess), comment out the ref to the JS file and the LESS file, and uncomment the main CSS file (or min.css). I'm sure there's easier ways to do it, this is just what my team and I do b/c they don't use web essentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure your Web Essentials to compile on save and build. That way you can always manually generate the CSS by saving the LESS file.

[image: LESS Options]

Optionally, you can configure Web Essentials to minify the generated CSS:

[image: CSS Options]

Also add a `StyleBundle` which loads the generated minified CSS file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"));
```

Comment: For me too, Web Essentials just works on the background updating the CSS whenever you change your LESS.